# Logging failures in JEE container managed authentication

Tags: http, authentication, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I am using HTTP Basic authentication on my Payara 4.1 application server and I am restricted to use JEE7 technology stack.

I would like to process failed authentication attempts to make them appear in application logs. Something like a `AuthenticationFailureHandler` in Spring Security would be great. Is there a way to have something similar in JEE7?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can use a custom logging handler: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#gklnk